# Calling functions from other contracts solidity

Tags: function, external, blockchain, contract, solidity

I am trying to create a new instance of the Taker contract from the Maker contract and send some value to it.

Then later I would like to send a value back to the Maker contract from the Taker contract

```
maker.change.value(5)(y);
```

However it cannot find the function called "change" and throws the error. The only possible explanation I can think of is that they need to be executed asynchronously but are compiled at the same time.

```
Untitled:27:3: Error: Member "change" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address
    maker.change.value(5)(y);
    ^----------^
```

(This is tested in Browser Solidity, Ethereum Studio and Truffle - all with the same error message)

Below is the full code.

I would be very grateful for any advice on how to solve this (and or references).

Thank you!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Maker {
uint x;

function Maker() {
    x = 5;
    Taker take = new Taker(this, 2);
    bool a = take.call.gas(200000).value(10)();
}

function change(uint val) external payable {
    x = val;
}
}

contract Taker {
uint y;
address maker;

function Taker(address makerAddr, uint val) {
    y = val;
    maker = makerAddr;
}

function sendChange() {
    maker.change.value(5)(y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked with me in Browser Solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract Maker {
uint x;

function Maker() {
   x = 5;
   Taker take = new Taker(this, 2);
   bool a = take.call.gas(200000).value(10)();
}

function change(uint val) external {
   x = val;
}
}

contract Taker {
   uint y;
   Maker maker;

   function Taker(address makerAddr, uint val) {
      y = val;
      maker = Maker(makerAddr);
 }

 function sendChange() {
    maker.change(5);
 }
 }
```